# ZIndex issues in React Native 0.60.5

Tags: react-native, animation, view

I am facing the problem with z-index in React Native 0.60.5 which is the lastest version now. I want  a red box to overlaps a blue box.

I have tried :

> 1. z-index :1 for a red box and -1 for a blue box.
> 2. z- index : 1000 for a red box and -1000 for a blue box.
> 3. no z-index for a red box and -1 for a blue box.

None of above works

Case 1:

```js
 < View
 style = {
  {
   zIndex: 1,
   height: 100,
   width: 100,
   backgroundColor: 'red',
  }
 }
 /> <
 View
 style = {
  {
   height: 100,
   width: 100,
   zIndex: -1,
   backgroundColor: 'blue',
   position: 'absolute',
  }
 }
 />
```

Case 2:

```js
 < View
 style = {
  {
   zIndex: 1000,
   height: 100,
   width: 100,
   backgroundColor: 'red',
  }
 }
 /> <
 View
 style = {
  {
   height: 100,
   width: 100,
   zIndex: -1000,
   backgroundColor: 'blue',
   position: 'absolute',
  }
 }
 />
```

Case 3:

```js
 < View
 style = {
  {
   height: 100,
   width: 100,
   backgroundColor: 'red',
  }
 }
 /> <
 View
 style = {
  {
   height: 100,
   width: 100,
   zIndex: -1,
   backgroundColor: 'blue',
   position: 'absolute',
  }
 }
 />
```

[Here is my app screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz9ds.png)

Comment: Removing position: 'absolute' should do the trick. Position:absolute goes above everything

Comment: If there is no absolute, it will follow the normal order. It means a blue box is above a red box.

Answer (score 0):

```
 View
 style = {
  {
   height: 100,
   width: 100,
   zIndex: -1000,
   backgroundColor: 'blue',
   position: 'absolute',
   top : 10,
   left : 0
  }
 }
 />
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit please ?

Comment: Well you are giving position absolute but you are not specifying the position which are needed to be specified when you're using absolute position view to align the items, unlike the relative positioned views